# Java Date Range Split by n parts Any Util method

Tags: java, date, split

I was wondering if Java has an Util method that splits a date into multiple parts according to an input.
Ex: Existing Date in DB- Start Date 01-Oct-2021,  End Date 30-Oct-2021

Compare the input dates to the existing date and determine whether it needs to be updated or a new record inserted in the database

```
Case#1 Input :  Start Date 10-Oct-2021,  End Date 20-Oct-2021
       Output:  1) 01-Oct-2021 to 09-Oct-2021 // update exiting record in db
                2) 10-Oct-2021 to 20-Oct-2021 // Create a new record
                3) 21-Oct-2021 to 30-Oct-2021 // Create a new record

Case#2 Input :  Start Date 01-Oct-2021,  End Date 20-Oct-2021 
       Output : 1) 01-Oct-2021 to 20-Oct-2021  // update exiting record in db
                2) 21-Oct-2021 to 30-Oct-2021  // Create a new record

Case#3 Input :  Start Date 01-Oct-2021,  End Date 31-Oct-2021 
       Output : 1) 01-Oct-2021 to 31-Oct-2021 // update exiting record in db

Case#4 Input :  Start Date 01-Nov-2021,  End Date 10-Nov-2021 
       Output : 1) 01-Nov-2021 to 10-Nov-2021  // Dont change the exiting record, Create a 
                                                 new record
```

etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The logic of this isn't easy to understand. It looks like you're trying to solve a custom bit of business logic by interpreting dates. The Java LocalDate library can process dates very well, so is your starting point.

Comment: No, there isn’t any such utility method. I don’t think it should be hard to write and test your own, though.